# How do I debug a server that doesn't release its DHCP IP?

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp

It looks like my server keeps on asking for a DHCP address, yet doesn't release old ones. Previously, it was directly connected to my ISP and it held on to thousands of DHCP leases (it might have caused a city-wide DoS).

The server can still reach the internet. The issue doesn't cause connectivity issues for the server, but everyone else can't use the claimed IP addresses.

In an attempt to isolate the issue, I connected it to LAN. Unsurprisingly, it exhausted the router's IP pool. All of the IP addresses were reachable from localhost (I can ping it, <1ms delay), but not from the outside.

I don't have much experience with `dhclient`, or how a server handles acquiring/releasing IP addresses. `/etc/network/interfaces` is unmodified, except for `allow-hotplug ens5`

The problem might have started when either I

- replaced `sendmail` with `postfix` (`apt-get install postfix`, nothing else)
- ran `apt-get upgrade` (updated the kernel and some PHP modules, nothing else)

I don't have any custom scripts on the server. `dmesg` is clean. It's a web server, and most of what I do is either on `nginx` or in-site (Wordpress).

How do I even begin to debug this? I haven't encountered such a thing in the past.

```
root@placeholder-not-actual-hostname:~# uname -a
Linux placeholder-not-actual-hostname 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `ip a`:

```
root@placeholder-not-actual-hostname:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:cb:4e:48:4e:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.249.2/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.3/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.4/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.5/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.6/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.7/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.8/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.9/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.10/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.11/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.12/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.13/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.14/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.15/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.16/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.17/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.18/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.19/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.20/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.21/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.22/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.23/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.24/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.25/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.26/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.27/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.28/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.29/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.30/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.31/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.32/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.33/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.34/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.35/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.36/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.37/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.38/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.39/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.40/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.41/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.42/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.43/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.44/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.45/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.46/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.47/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.48/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.49/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.50/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.51/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.52/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.53/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.54/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.55/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.56/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.57/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.58/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.59/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.60/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.61/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.62/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.63/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.64/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.65/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.66/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.67/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.68/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.69/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.70/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.72/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.73/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.74/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.75/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.76/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.77/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.78/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.79/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.80/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.81/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.82/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.83/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.84/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.85/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.86/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.87/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.88/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.89/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.90/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.91/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.92/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.93/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.94/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.95/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.96/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.97/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.98/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.99/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.100/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.101/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.102/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.103/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.104/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.105/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.106/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.107/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.108/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.109/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.110/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.111/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.112/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.113/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.114/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.115/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.116/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.117/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.118/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.119/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.120/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.121/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.122/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.123/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.124/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.125/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.126/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.127/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.128/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.129/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.130/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.131/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.132/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.133/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.134/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.135/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.136/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.137/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.138/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.139/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.140/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.141/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.142/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.143/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.144/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.145/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.146/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.147/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.148/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.149/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.150/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.151/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.152/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.153/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.154/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.155/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.156/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.157/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.158/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.159/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.160/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.161/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.162/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.163/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.164/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.165/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.166/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.167/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.168/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.169/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.170/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.171/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.172/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.173/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.174/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.175/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.176/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.177/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.178/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.179/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.180/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.181/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.182/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.183/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.184/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.185/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.186/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.187/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.188/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.189/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.190/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.191/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.192/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.193/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.194/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.195/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.196/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.197/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.198/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.199/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.200/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.254/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.249.71/24 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global secondary ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e2cb:4eff:fe48:4e28/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:d3:cd:e0:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f3c8:a059:15d5:5ec7/64 scope link flags 800
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Full contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`. `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` is empty.

```
root@placeholder:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens5
allow-hotplug ens5
iface ens5 inet dhcp
```

Comment: What is the complete content of `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Updated. `ens5` is an Ethernet connection, and is the interface in question. I've verified that the router is not at fault.

Comment: Please show the included files as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

I've noted in my answer that acquiring IP addresses works fine, but releasing leases doesn't work.

I've checked out `/etc/dhcp/`, and I found two interesting directories:

```
root@placeholder:~# ls -lah /etc/dhcp/
total 744K
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Feb 17 08:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 104 root root 720K Feb 18 11:57 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.4K Nov 26  2016 debug
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Aug 21  2010 dhclient-enter-hooks.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Feb 17 13:46 dhclient-exit-hooks.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.7K Dec 25 22:41 dhclient.conf
```

I just found out that `dhclient` actually has hooks for when 1.) DHCP lease is acquired and 2.) DHCP lease is released. The `.d` directories contain bash scripts that run when the events mentioned fired.

Since the server was having trouble releasing DHCP leases, I checked out `dhclient-exit-hooks.d`. Sure enough, there was a faulty script. There was a `sendmail` script in there that always failed despite returning 0 (missing directory, since `sendmail` was uninstalled).

Comment: P.S. I removed the offending script. Just a regular `rm`, since I didn't need it.